# highchart - how to deal with flags overlapping problem?

Tags: highcharts, flags

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOIea.jpg)my chart should display many flags, but I want to display without overlapping between flags. but I found some flags overlap.
how can I display without overlap between flags? 
My customer does not allow any text overlap between flags. let me know how to solve it. (I attached another picture with red circle point.)
Scandal & Metal Trade flag are overlapped. but we couldn't set differently y position for each data due to it comes from table.
how do I exclude these case regarding flag displaying?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2nHF.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/csjuf.jpg)

```
function addSeriesDataChartView(data, cond){
var seriesOptionsPrdct = {};
seriesOptionsPrdct.id = cond;
seriesOptionsPrdct.lineWidth= 2;
seriesOptionsPrdct.type= 'line';
seriesOptionsPrdct.dashStyle ="shortdash";
seriesOptionsPrdct.showInNavigator=false;

seriesOptionsPrdct.name = "이벤트";
seriesOptionsPrdct.type= 'flags';
seriesOptionsPrdct.shape= 'squarepin';
seriesOptionsPrdct.data= data;
data: [{
  bse_dt : "1996-07-19"
  code_cntry:"US"
  code_mkt;"STCK"
  evt_kwd:"US municipal bond"
  long_ewi_class:"1"
  prc_clos_dt:"1996-07-19"
  title:"US municipal bond"
  x:837734400000
  y:638.73 },
 {
  bse_dt : "1996-09-23"
  code_cntry:"US"
  code_mkt;"STCK"
  evt_kwd:"Fed Meeting"
  long_ewi_class:"1"
  prc_clos_dt:"1996-09-23"
  title:"Fed Meeting"
  x:843436800000
  y:686.48 },
 {
  bse_dt : "1996-11-06"
  code_cntry:"US"
  code_mkt;"STCK"
  evt_kwd:"Scandal"
  long_ewi_class:"1"
  prc_clos_dt:"1996-11-06"
  title:"Scandal"
  x:847238400000
  y:724.59},
 {
  bse_dt : "1996-11-20"
  code_cntry:"US"
  code_mkt;"STCK"
  evt_kwd:"Metal Trade"
  long_ewi_class:"1"
  prc_clos_dt:"1996-11-20"
  title:"Metal Trade"
  x:848448000000
  y:743.95}]

seriesOptionsPrdct.color= mrktChartColor.prdctLine[0];
seriesOptionsPrdct.onSeries=$(".gnb_dep02 li a.on").attr('id');
seriesOptionsPrdct.onSeries='dataseries';
//seriesOptionsPrdct.lineWidth= 1;


chartMain.addSeries(seriesOptionsPrdct);
}
```

//

Comment: You'll have to show us your code to get any kind of meaningful answer.

Comment: Hi @heesoo, Please provide us some minimal live example of this problem. With standard options this issue is not noticeable: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/b32qgup0/

Comment: Have you tried to set series.flags.allowOverlapX property to false? https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/o9ajp1L0/

Comment: - overlap code-

Comment: my issue is some text is overlapping. customer does not allow any text overlapping. for example one flag text is [hello], and the other flag is [hello world] then, the text of first flag [ llo] is overlap the other flag's [hello]. that's the situation..I will update the image example.

Comment: I've tried already with [allowOverlapX], but it still shows overlap between flags, any space shouldn't be overlapped between flags. that's what solution that I want. If I apply the length of flag, that is 'flag size', and then the text overflow the flag squarepin type. the size of flag is automatic based on text.

Comment: Hello @heesoo, Again, please reproduce this situation in some online code editor. Your problem can be caused by many factors and without seeing your code I can not help you.

Comment: how can I reproduce the code? because our system environment closed network. so I can't access online. I will try to copy the code in detail

Comment: Please only use the code related with Highcharts and create very simple live demo (for example like this: jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/b32qgup0) to show the problem.

Comment: hi. we produce flag data from table array data. so I attached data sample that I wrote.  we calculate x axis from the bse_dt , and  then set X, on the other hand Y axis set from the value of prc_clos_dt .

Comment: hi. I reproduce the code. if you need more let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I successfully reproduced the situation you describe: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/dn7poc81/

Your problem is caused by `'squarepin'` shape type, which currently has problem with overlapping. You need to use temporarily `'flag'` shape type:

```
series: [{
    type: 'flags',
    // shape: 'squarepin',
    ...
}]
```

This issue looks like a bug, so I reported it on Highcharts GitHub: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/9726